# Spark textFileStream on S3

Tags: spark-streaming

Should the file name contain a number for the tetFileStream to pickup? my program is picking up new files only if the file name contains a number. Ignoring all other files even if they are new. Is there any setting I need to change for picking up all the files? Please help

Comment: No it takes all the file in the particular directory. Can you paste some code for better help !

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. Ran into another issue. My spark streaming code is working perfectly when I submit it locally in my VM. It is reading files from S3 and writing output to ELK. But, when I submit the jar into EMR cluster it is giving warning saying "error reading files " and not reading at all. Is it some kind of permissions issue? I am giving all the necessary keys for my S3 bucket. Any views?

Answer (score 0):

No. it scans the directory for new files which appear within the window. If you are writing to S3, do a direct write with your code, as the file doesn't appear until the final close() —no need to rename. In constrast, if you are working with file streaming sources against normal filesystems, you should create out of the scanned dir and rename in at the end —otherwise work-in-progress files may get read. And once read: never re-read.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Ran into another issue. My spark streaming code is working perfectly when I submit it locally in my VM. It is reading files from S3 and writing output to ELK. But, when I submit the jar into EMR cluster it is giving warning saying "error reading files " and not reading at all. Is it some kind of permissions issue? I am giving all the necessary keys for my S3 bucket. Any views?

Comment: that's all it says? No stack trace?

Comment: When I submit using EMR Console in YARN mode, I haven't got much of information. It says Running, but does not read anything from S3. Following is the stack trace if I submit manually on EMR Master Instance terminal. FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192) so on and so forth

Comment: I need to point out that while my local VM is Cloudera Manager, the target Cluster is an EMR one. The jar for local testing is built on Spark 1.6.1, while the target one is built on Spark 2.0.1

Comment: mixing versions of Spark is dangerous; the API does change, and 2.0  is not link-time compatible with 2.0. Rebuild locally against 2.0.x before resubmitting

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours on analyzing stack trace, I figured out that the problem is S3 address. I was providing "s3://mybucket", which was working for Spark 1.6 and Scala 2.10.5. On Spark 2.0 (and Scala 2.11), it must be provided as "s3://mybucket/". May be some Regex related stuff. Working fine now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: oh, so you were using a short path of "s3://bucket" without a path? That may be interpreted as a reference to a home directory, so would be qualified as a path of bucket/users/$USER where $USER = you. This happens on the command line, and is a real pain. I'd personally like to fix that ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13648 ) but worry about what ill break